# Php strpos mismatch

Tags: php, parsing, strpos

i have this problem with php and the function strpos

i read from a parse file an array of string in the variable auslin and i want to find the position of the word A, B, C, D, E, ...........X,Y,Z that are in the variable  array $lettera[$ii]

```
 $lettera[1]="A";
 $lettera[1]="B";
 ......
 $lettera[26]="Z";
```

For every value of  auslin --> $mystring = $auslin; when i match with $lettera[$ii] , i obtain position 24

```
    $findme   = $lettera[$ii];
       $pos= strpos($mystring, $findme);

if the name is Lucchini Valentini --->Position of V the value of pos is 24
if the name is  Cigarini Biagianti--->Position of V the value of pos is 24
if the name is  Estigarribia Benassi --->Position of B the value of pos is 24


this is the code


    $pos1[$i]=0; $pos2[$i]=0; $pos3[$i]=0;
    $lunghezza=strlen($auslin);
    $flag=false;
    $indice=1;
    $mystring = $auslin; // in my string there are the line that i have read from a parse
    for ($ii=1; $ii<=26; $ii++) {
    $findme   = $lettera[$ii];
    $pos= strpos($mystring, $findme);
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {    
    echo "<br>valore pos : $pos<br>";
    if ($pos == 1) {
            $pos1[$i]=$pos;         
            $pos=false;     
    } else {
        if ($flag === false) {      
      $aus=$pos;
      $pos2[$i]=$aus;
      $flag=true;
      $indice++;
        $pos=false;
    } else {
        $pos2[$i]=$aus2;
            $pos3[$i]=$aus3;        
        if ($aus2 == $aus3) {    
    } else {
        $pos3[$i]=$pos;
        $indice++;
         $ii=27;
    }       
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

this is the file that done the parse  and that call prova1.php that is over

```
<?php

$squadraweb1=trim($_GET['squadraweb1']);
$squadraweb2=trim($_GET['squadraweb2']);



$squadra1=intval($_GET['Squadra1']);
$squadra2=intval($_GET['Squadra1']);

$url=$_GET['url1'];

echo "<br>valore di squadraweb1 $squadraweb1, valore di URL $url<br>";
echo "<br>valore di squadraweb2 $squadraweb2,<br>";


////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////



include '../SERIEAITA/Dati/dati.php';




ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 

$valoresq1[1]="Atalanta";


for ($i=1; $i<=$ultima; $i++) {

$squadra[$i] = strtolower($valoresq1[$i]);  
////echo "<br>$i:".$squadra[$i]."<br>";


}   



//echo "<br>VALORE DI URL $url<br>";
$lines = file($url);

$indice=1;
$i=1;
//echo "<br>----------------------------------------<br>";
$flag=true;
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {


            $linea[$i]=strip_tags($line);
            $copiastringa[$i]=strip_tags($line);
            if (( $i>130 )  ){  
            echo "<br>$i:".$copiastringa[$i]."<br>";


            }
            $html[$i]=$line;
            $lineamin=strtolower ($linea[$i]);
            ////echo "<br>$i:$lineamin<br>";
            $aus=trim($lenamin);

if (( $i>300 )  ){  

echo "<br>entrato i :$i > 300";         

break;

}           


if (( $i>100 )  ){  

        //echo "<br>$i:-----------------<br>".$lineamin."<br>";
            ////echo "<br>---------------ENTRATO ------------------<br>";


$mystring = $lineamin;

$findme=strtolower($squadraweb1);


////echo "<br>SQUADRA".$squadra[$ii]."<br>";
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Notate l'uso di ===.  Il == non avrebbe risposto come atteso
// poiché la posizione di 'a' è nel primo carattere.

if ($flag === true){

//echo "<br>entro dento flag 143:".$copiastringa[143]."<br>";


if ($pos === false) {
  //  //echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {

    $flag=false;
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";



    //echo "<br>-----------------------------------------<br>";
    //echo "<br>$i---------->:RIGO69".$copiastringa[$i-2]."<br>";   
    //echo "<br>$i---------->:RIGO68".$copiastringa[$i-1]."<br>";
    //echo "<br>$i---------->:RIGO69".$copiastringa[$i]."<br>";
    //echo "<br>$i---------->:RUGI70".$copiastringa[$i+1]."<br>";
    //echo "<br>$i---------->:RUGI71".$copiastringa[$i+2]."<br>";

        //echo "<br>-----------------------------------------<br>";
    $pieces = explode($squadraweb2, $mystring);
    $reti2=(trim($pieces[1]));

    $pieces = explode($squadraweb1, $pieces[0]);


    $reti1=(trim($pieces[1] ));
     echo "<br> valore di reti segnate da squadra 1 è<br>$reti1<br>"; // piece2 
          echo "<br> valore di reti segnate da squadra 2 è<br>$reti2<br>"; // piece2 

    $reti1=intval($reti1);
    $reti2=intval($reti2);

    $controlloinizio=$i;
    echo"<br>rigo 58 valore controllo inziio : $controlloinizio<br>";
    //$i=$ultima;




}



    }           




$mystring = $lineamin;
$findme   = "arbitro";
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Notate l'uso di ===.  Il == non avrebbe risposto come atteso
// poiché la posizione di 'a' è nel primo carattere.
if ($pos === false) {
  //  //echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    //echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    //echo " and exists at position $pos";
    $controllofine=$i;
    $ii=$ultima;




}

    }   

$i++;           

}           

if ($controllofine >20) {

$controllofine=$controlloinizio+18;

}



echo "<br>---------------------<br>controllo inizio $controlloinizio |||||||||||| controllo fine $controllofine<br>----------------------------------<br>";

////////////////////
///////////////////////////INSERISCO NEL DATABASE PARTITE ON LINE/////////////////


$tot2=$squadraweb1;
$tot3=$squadraweb2;






$lettera[1]="A";
$lettera[2]="B";
$lettera[3]="C";
$lettera[4]="D";
$lettera[5]="E";
$lettera[6]="F";
$lettera[7]="G";
$lettera[8]="H";
$lettera[9]="I";
$lettera[10]="L";
$lettera[11]="M";
$lettera[12]="N";
$lettera[13]="O";
$lettera[14]="P";
$lettera[15]="Q";
$lettera[16]="R";
$lettera[17]="S";
$lettera[18]="T";
$lettera[19]="U";
$lettera[20]="V";
$lettera[21]="Z";
$lettera[22]="K";
$lettera[23]="J";
$lettera[24]="W";
$lettera[25]="X";
$lettera[26]="Y";


echo "<br>VALORE TOT2 :$tot2<br>";
echo "<br>VALORE TOT3 :$tot3<br>";



echo "<br>------------TESTO----------<br>";
for ($i=$controlloinizio+5; $i<=$controllofine; $i++) {

$auslin=htmlentities($linea[$i]);


include 'prova1.php';




}



      echo "<br>-----------------<br>------------------<br>VALORE TOT3 finale $tot3<br>";
        echo "<br>VALORE TOT2 finale$tot2<br>";


echo "<br>-------------------valore finale tot----------<br>$tot<br>----------------<br>";

$ora=date("g").":".date("i");


$parts = explode(':', $ora); 
$ora=mktime($parts[0], $parts[1]); 







//if ((($realTime - $schedTime) / 3600) >= 3) { 
    // differenza tra tempo reale e tempo schedulato maggiore di 3 ore 
//} 





include 'Online/partiteonline.php';




/////////////////////
//include 'selectserieaita';



$incremento1=0;   ////DI QUANTO INCREMENTARE NEL DATABASE LA PRIMA SQQUADRA
$incremento2=0;    ////DI QUANTO INCREMENTARE NEL DATABASE LA SECONDA SQQUADRA


$pvinte1=0;
$pvinte2=0;

$ppareggiate1=0;
$ppareggiate2=0;

$pperse1=0;
$pperse2=0;





if ($reti1 > $reti2) {


$pvinte1=1;


$incremento1=3;



}




if ($reti1 < $reti2) {


$incremento2=3;

$pvinte2=0;




}


if ($reti1 == $reti2) {


$incremento1=1;
$incremento2=1;

$ppareggiate1=1;
$ppareggiate2=1;




}





include 'Aggiornaserieaita/aggiornaserieaita.php';


?>
```

and the file parsed in html with this content, but i've not problem, my only problem is when i call prova1.php and i 've this mismatch

ATALANTA   2           LIVORNO     0 
 22' De Luca
 59' Denis

Formazioni     Ammoniti 
 Consigli               Bardi
 Raimondi               Castellini
 Lucchini               Valentini
 Yepes                  Ceccherini
 Del Grosso             Mbaye
 Cigarini               Biagianti
 Estigarribia           Benassi
 Carmona                Greco
 Bonaventura            Gemiti
 Denis                  Emeghara
 De Luca                Paulinho
              Sostituzioni

```
  Arbitro: De Marco di Chiavari
```

Comment: Have you checked the length of the string you are passing and the value of each `$lettera[$ii]`?

Comment: sure , i add that i this value  mismatch is only  when i put the value from the parse.

Comment: I don't see any reason for `strpos('Lucchini Valentini','V')` to be `24`. It should be `9`. Could you paste your full code?

Comment: Sure , this the code , not all, but interesting code
$lettera[1]="A";


$lettera[26]="Z";


echo "<br>VALORE TOT2 :$tot2<br>";
echo "<br>VALORE TOT3 :$tot3<br>";



echo "<br>------------TESTO----------<br>";
for ($i=$controlloinizio+5; $i<=$controllofine; $i++) {
 
$auslin=htmlentities($linea[$i]);
 

include 'prova1.php';




}  and prova1.php is over, the value of auslin is from the file that i 'm trying to parse

Comment: Please edit your question and add it, hard to read from comments.

Comment: yes it's, but the problem is only in strpos, all is ok , i don't understand why strpos give position 24 and no 9. I've try all htmlentities, strip_tags etc. etc. for the value from the file that i read (parse), but nothing, the value is 24, i don't understand.

Comment: Is that your complete code of prova1.php? I don't see where `pos1` is being declared

Comment: in the first line   $pos1[$i] 0; and i after i recall it in   $pos1[$i]=$pos;   inside a if, but the problem is strpos  if i done echo $pos  after strpos(mystring, findme) i obtain only 24

Comment: Testing your code seems to give the correct output _[here](http://codepad.org/VceMpVsw)_ The only advice I can give you is to reproduce your problem or debug more to find out what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: I don't know this site, ok Cheezburger thank so much for your time.